# Homebrew's LLVM@12 "fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found" on macOS

Tags: macos, llvm, clang++, libstdc++

1.Install LLVM `brew install llvm@12`

2.create dest.cpp

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
  // code
```

3.when i run `/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/bin/clang++ dest.cpp -o dest`, i get:

```
fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found
```

1.i add directory bits which contains a file stdc++.h to path : `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm@12/12.0.1_1/Toolchains/LLVM12.0.1.xctoolchain/usr/include`, i get the same fatal

2.i add it to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm@12/12.0.1_1/include` too, but result is the same

PS.the stdc++.h file is correct, because I use it successful when I add it `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include`, but it does not work when i add it to llvm@12

I have to have stdc++.h here because my work is to test hundreds of codes and most of them have the stdc++.h, it is too difficult for me to change the headers to what they exactly need.

**what is the trouble?** is it possible to have stdc++.h while I run /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@12/bin/clang++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 2):

bits/stdc++.h is a libstdc++-specific header file.

On Mac OS, the standard library is libc++, which does not have that file.
(it's a non-standard implementation detail of libstdc++).

If you are unwilling/unable to change your source files, I can think of two options:

- Install libstdc++ on your Mac.   This will probably work, but (I believe) that Mac OS is not a supported platform for libstdc++.
- Create your own file `stdc++.h` and put it in a folder named `bits` and point clang at it.  You'll need to figure out what to put into the file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in the second option, i still need to change de source files, because the source code is ```#include <bits/stdc++.h>```, and if i use my own file stdc++.h, i need to change it to ```#include "bits/stdc++.h"```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-I /path/to/headerfile` option with Clang++ to let the compiler know where else to search for the header files that are not found in its standard search directories:

`clang++ dest.cpp -o dest -I /path/to/bits`

Comment: i run this command and get ```error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
``` then i have to change ```#include<bits/stdc++.h>```to ```#include "bits/stdc++.h"``` , is there a way to solve it without changing the dest.cpp?

Comment: Yes. In order to have separate control over the search paths use `-iquote` for quote-formatted includes and `-isystem` for angle-bracket forms of include. So in your case, you can use `-isystem` instead of `-I` and this way you will not need to change your code.